# how to call multiple buttons at the same time

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, button

I am having a problem in calling multiple buttons at the same time because each buttons works a different process there are more than 78 folders.

I want to call all the buttons at the same time in a single button called button4. Now it's calling button1 only and not working for button2.

Is there any way to call these buttons at the same time?

My code is:

```
    private void button4_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        button1.PerformClick();
        button2.PerformClick();


    }
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I'd say it is commonly not a good idea to actually 'click' buttons. You should probably go and call the event handling methods of the respective buttons

Comment: what is the onClick of button1?

Comment: Can u  pls tell me  where i shold change , I am new in c#

Comment: The code shown works perfectly. If button 2 is not getting "clicked", check to make sure that it is enabled (set the `Enabled` property to true).

Comment: What do you mean by "at the same time"?. Are you going to run the tasks in parallel?

Answer (score 4):

You should in general not perform UI-style clicks on other buttons in order to invoke their behaviour.

Just call the respective event handling methods of the buttons you would like to "click".

example code:

```
private void button4_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   button1_Click_1(null, EventArgs.Empty);
   button2_Click_1(null, EventArgs.Empty);
   // and so on
}
```

Comment: @Ben you just taught me something. Thanks for that!

Comment: Uhh, what? **Why not?** Why shouldn't we do this? What's wrong with the `PerformClick()` method? This is exactly what it was intended for.

Comment: @Cody: Why should you want to put a Message into MessageQueue, wait an undefined time for the UI Thread to invoke another button's event handler? Especially if you are able to get the same effect from a simple method call. 
**Or to quote a famous aphorism: "All problems in computer science can be solved by another level of indirection"**

Comment: That's all very nice, but none of it is relevant here. I asked specifically about the `PerformClick` method, not about `MessageQueue` or anything else. That's emphatically *not* how `PerformClick` is implemented, and not what it does. You could read the documentation, or you could make assumptions. I prefer to take the former route. After checking to ensure that the button is "clickable" (meaning it is enabled and visible--which is something you would have to re-implement yourself if one were to follow your suggestion), the method calls the protected `OnClick` method of the `Button` class.

Comment: Looks like we've prevented 1) redundant code and 2) an additional level of redundancy (invoking the event through a delegate). Score 1 for `PerformClick`, -1 for calling the event handler method directly. Calling event handler methods directly is *not* idiomatic .NET code, and there are good reasons for it.

Comment: @cody: State where you got your information from. IMHO enabling / disabling the button (and thus preventing it from being clicked) is a separate concern and should be dealt with separatly. But I guess one can differ on that. Somehow I get the feeling you enjoy downvoting

Comment: Somehow I get the feeling you enjoy accusing people of downvoting... I haven't downvoted this answer. What do you mean where I got my information from? What information do you dispute? How in the world is it a separate concern that the button is disabled? The event handler method should be able to expect that it *only* gets called when the button is enabled and clickable. It shouldn't have to perform validation checks. The `PerformClick` method was included specifically for this reason, because it's not a good idea to call event handler methods directly. You made a claim you can't defend.

Comment: @cody: I can't find the information regarding your claims(button has to be visible/enabled) in the online documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.button.performclick.aspx)
You are of course right in, that the event handler method should only be called if this a good thing to do, given the application's current state. However, I prefer to just disable the buttons when application state dictates to not call methods (e.g. I would disable both button1 and button4). On a different topic: How about we transfer this discussion to a chat room?

Comment: I don't do chat (still boycotting that feature). And I'm not terribly interested in arguing. I just wasn't sure if you had some particular reason or justification for your claim that you shouldn't use `PerformClick`, because I don't just assume I'm always right. Apparently not, so I'm satisfied.

Comment: You are still not presenting anything to back up your own claim of `PerformClick()`'s behaviour. I would like to read up on that.

Comment: Have you checked the documentation? Another good place to look is the [.NET Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

You should refactor the other events to call well-named methods.

Say button1 does some initialization; it should look like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Initialize();
}
```

Say button2 finalizes that intialization; it should look like this:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FinalizeInitialization();
}
```

Then if button4 does all of this; it should look like this:

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Initialize();
    FinalizeInitialization();

    WhateverElseButton4ShouldDo();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Under most circumstances, you shouldn't call `PerformClick()` at all. Instead, you should call the same methods your event handlers call. So, if clicking button 3 should behave as click clicking button 1 and then button 2, you should have code like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SomeAction();
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AnotherAction();
}

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SomeAction();
    AnotherAction();
}
```

(As a side note, your buttons should have descriptive names, not `button1` and the like.)

Comment: Same comment as that to yas4891's answer: why should we not call the `PerformClick()` method? Why is calling the event handler method directly the *better* option?

Comment: @Cody, note that in my code, I'm not calling the event handler, but some method that is also called by the event handler. That's because you probably don't want to actually click the button. You want to do the same thing clicking the button *currently* does. But in the future, you might want for example to remove button 2, but keep button 3 with its current functionality. In other words, you don't want to say “do the same thing button 1 does”, you want to say “do X”, where X is what button 1 currently does.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. The design you show (refactoring the logic out into a separate method, called both by the event handler and your code) is preferable to either of the two alternatives. Didn't read the code sample closely enough, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

We can't say what those button click handlers do. So it's hard to say what's wrong. But try moving the code away from button click handlers. Create some class that contains code that should run after button click. Then call this class' methods from button click handlers. It will be easier to debug and test that code.

```
    public class ButtonActions
    {
        public void DoSomething() {...}
        public void DoSomething2() {...}
        public void DoSomething3() {...}

        public void DoAll()
        {
            DoSomething();
            DoSomething2();
            DoSomething3();
        }

    }

    // here instead of clicking all buttons call method that does it all
    protected void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var buttonActions = new ButtonActions();
        buttonActions.DoAll();
    }
```